# AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iterkeys'

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, dictionary

I'm creating the stable matching project in Python, and I'm trying to iterate over the keys of a `dict` using `iterkeys()`, but I'm getting the following error:
`AttributeError: dict object has no attribute iterkeys`

This is my dict:

```
preferred_rankings_men = {
    'ryan':     ['lizzy', 'sarah', 'zoey', 'daniella'],
    'josh':     ['sarah', 'lizzy', 'daniella', 'zoey'],
    'blake':    ['sarah', 'daniella', 'zoey', 'lizzy'],
    'connor':   ['lizzy', 'sarah', 'zoey', 'daniella']
}
```

And here is my function:

```
def init_free_men():
    for man in preferred_rankings_men.iterkeys():
        free_men.append(man)
```

Answer (score 10):

`dict.iterkeys()` method is [deprecated in Python 3](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0469/). The equivalent code would be:

```
for man in preferred_rankings_men:
```

Answer (score 4):

`.iterkeys()` is the old Python 2 method for getting an iterator over the keys. In Python 3, if you must use a method call, you'd use `.keys()` which gets an iterable *view* of the `dict`s keys. That said, the simplest solution is not to call a method at all; `dict`s are already iterables of their keys, so:

```
def init_free_men():
    for man in preferred_rankings_men:
        free_men.append(man)
```

works efficiently on both Python 2 and Python 3, and can even be simplified further to:

```
def init_free_men():
    free_men.extend(preferred_rankings_men)
```